# Exception raised with createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Can someone explain if any issue has been reported with the Firebase Authentication Javascript SDK.

Every time I try to create a new account with :

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

it raises the following error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
```

My settings :

- I am using Firebase 9
- Firebase is initialised correctly with the configuration settings
- the Sign-In Method : Email/Password is enabled in the console

Comment: Also posted to https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/b9p91uFoOZI, where I responded. I also answered below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the code you shared isn't working, but the v9.15 SDK is working without problems for me here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/auth-v9?file=index.js

Code:

```
const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, "user@domain.com", "password").then((credentials)=> {
  console.log(credentials);
  console.log(credentials.user);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
})
```

This logs:

> Initializing Firebase
>
> UserCredentialImpl {user: UserImpl, providerId: null, _tokenResponse: {…}, operationType: 'signIn'}
>
> UserImpl {providerId: 'firebase', proactiveRefresh: ProactiveRefresh, reloadUserInfo: {…}, reloadListener: null, uid: '9X2qcCSN9vU4K2IhBSWExW3Hlix1', …}

Which looks correct to me.

Comment: Hello, thanks. After your comment, I did try again and it worked. then, it stopped working again. I am wondering if this is due to a usage limitation ?